# UITableView reload crash

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, reload

I'm facing this problem: There's a UIViewController which contains a UITableView, I have method in this Controller executed by a delegate which reloads the UITableView. If I pop the ViewController at the time the method is executing I get the following "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error:

```
#0  0x35df2c98 in objc_msgSend
#1  0x3556b8fc in -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _spacingForExtraSeparators]
#2  0x3556b380 in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _adjustExtraSeparators]
#3  0x3556b21e in -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
#4  0x355175fa in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
#5  0x34d8cf02 in -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:]
#6  0x30af4bb4 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
#7  0x30af496c in CALayerLayoutIfNeeded
#8  0x30afa1c4 in CA::Context::commit_transaction
#9  0x30af9fd6 in CA::Transaction::commit
#10 0x30af3054 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback
#11 0x34df6a34 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
#12 0x34df8464 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers
#13 0x34df975a in __CFRunLoopRun
#14 0x34d89ec2 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#15 0x34d89dca in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#16 0x3222941e in GSEventRunModal
#17 0x322294ca in GSEventRun
#18 0x35540d68 in -[UIApplication _run]
#19 0x3553e806 in UIApplicationMain
#20 0x00002474 in main at main.m:14
```

I've tried to release and not release the tableView when the Controller's dealloc executes but I get the same error.

I hope someone can help me! It will be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

enable nszombie first and find out what is creating error

[UITableview have EXT_BAD_ACCESS then scrolling down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591116/uitableview-have-ext-bad-access-then-scrolling-down/5591134#5591134)
good luck

Comment: Thanks mate, I've enabled nszombie but I haven't got any feedback. At that point (table reload) the app crashes, if you have any other advice it will be great otherwise I guess I'll have to look deeply at the lasts instructions.